# How to Access images on android cell phone

Tags: android, python

I have an android phone (Galaxy note). When I plug it to my pc via a cord, I have an entry of GT-N7000 shown in the portable devices section.
How can I access its files (images for example) using a python script?

Comment: Probably the OS of your computer is important. Is your phone, or rather your SD card, mounted as a drive? I.e., on windows, is a drive letter assigned to it?

Comment: You could use `adb` (a tool which ships with the Android SDK).

Comment: I'm using windows 7 and 8. my phone and sd card are not mounted.